# Invalid Parameter Value when Setting Lookup Id from JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, lookup

I have the below code for a JavaScript button which works fine

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 

var entitlementQuery = "SELECT  Application_Entitlement_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}' limit 1";
result = sforce.connection.query(entitlementQuery); 
records = result.getArray("records"); 

var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id, Name FROM CaseTeamRole WHERE Name = 'Requestor'");
var crRecords = qr.getArray("records");
var rec = crRecords[0];


if(records[0]){ 
  var relatedAccount = records[0]; 
  try{ 
    var recToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Case");

    var recordTypeQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Name,Id from RecordType WHERE developername = 'WE_Application'");
    var recordTypeQueryResult = recordTypeQuery.getArray("records");
    recToCreate.RecordTypeId = recordTypeQueryResult[0].Id;

    var queueNameQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Queue.DeveloperName, QueueId from QueueSobject WHERE Queue.DeveloperName = 'Wex_Europe_Applications'");
    var queueNameQueryResult = queueNameQuery.getArray("records");
    recToCreate.OwnerId = queueNameQueryResult[0].QueueId;

    >>adding BusinessHours code here

    recToCreate.AccountId = '{!Opportunity.AccountId}';  
    recToCreate.Subject = '{!Opportunity.Name}';  
    recToCreate.Origin = "Customer Application";
    recToCreate.Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
    recToCreate.User__c = '{!Opportunity.OwnerId}';

    recToCreate.EntitlementId = relatedAccount.Application_Entitlement_ID__c;


    var result = sforce.connection.create([recToCreate]);


    var ct = new sforce.SObject("CaseTeamMember");
    ct.MemberId = "{!$User.Id}";
    ct.parentId = result[0].id;
    ct.TeamRoleID = rec.Id;

    var result = sforce.connection.create([ct]);


    // check that Case has been created
    if(result[0].success == "true"){
      location.reload();
    }
    else{
      alert("An Error has Occurred. Error: " + result[0].errors.message);
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    alert("An Error has Occurred. Error: " + e);
  }


}
```

I'm now trying to set the Business Hours for the Case, that's being created through the button and I've written

```
var businessHoursQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE Name = 'Wex Europe CS Working Hours'");
var bhQueryResult = businessHoursQuery.getArray("records");
alert("bhQueryResult contains " + bhQueryResult); 
recToCreate.BusinessHours = bhQueryResult;
```

My alert confirms that `bhQueryResult` contains the 18 character BusinessHours Id but I then hit an error

> Invalid Parameter Value

and I'm not sure why?

I do have read & edit access on the BusinessHours field, for the record's that're being created by the button.

Comment: try to use 15 digit id and check if it solve your problem.

Comment: @TusharSharma could you please let me know how to convert the 18 character Id to 15 in JavaScript?

Comment: use this `var newId =bhQueryResult.substring(0,15);`

Comment: @TusharSharma I found the solution to the issue and tested it using your suggestion & without. The 18 character Id was accepted in the end but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `businessHoursQuery.getArray("records")` returns array.

To retrieve the first result from the array, try -

```
var bhQueryResult = businessHoursQuery.getArray("records");
recToCreate.BusinessHoursId = bhQueryResult[0].Id;
```

Note that `BusinessHours` needs to be changed to `BusinessHoursId`, as shown in the [Field Reference Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/13/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_field_names_reference.pdf).

For debugging I would suggest using `console.log('===bhQueryResult===',bhQueryResult);`

and check in the browser console, to see what the actual result is. Use F12 to open the console.

Comment: Thanks, the log displays the 18 character Id & the type BusinessHours in the console. The console also shows to errors 'Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" ' and 'Uncaught Error: Backbone.history has already been started' does that help? I also tried using `BusinessHoursId` but this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @AlexS are you sure `bhQueryResult` contains only id not array. as per my knowledge `getArray("records")` always return array.